# Spring Security Session

Tags: session, spring-security

I am confused about it. I've set up Spring Security successfully(role based access etc.), but what I don't understand is how to say add something to the session created by Spring? Or should I use another session for storing DTO attributes? And if I use my own session will Spring Security protect it? Its not transparent to me at all:

```html
<p id="layoutdims">
    <strong>
        Logged in as <security:authentication property="principal.username" />
    </strong>
    <strong>
        Logged in as <% HttpSession hs = request.getSession();          %>
        <%=hs.getAttribute("principal.username") %>
    </strong>
</p>
```

if Spring Security uses main session, why did `hs.getAttribute` gave me null? I feel really stupid about it, especially when I've done the most complex bit.

Answer (score 0):

try to get session object as follow

```java
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)
        RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session= attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
```

Comment: I was able to drag something with name SECURITY_CONTEXT something. I feel this approach is like digging the guts, could you please omit my concrete example and show me how you do it? Say with handlers? @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "reg")
 public String blablaBlabla(Model model) say in here?